# reading every line in a text file issue in C

Tags: c, output, text-files

Code:

```
#define maxWords 200
//finput is the file
char tempWord[maxWords];
(for i = 0; i < lineCounter(f); i++)
{
     fgets(tempWord, maxWords, finput);
     printf("%s", tempWord);
}
```

The lineCounter function works fine and outputs the right amount of lines in the text file. But for some reason it prints only 150 lines out of 1500 lines which I don't understand. I've been trying other functions such as fscanf and others and I still have the same issue. They all print out text but not the WHOLE text file.

Even if I put `i < 1500` as the condition in the for-loop I still have this problem. Does anyone know why? Also I tried in while-loop form too but no luck.

Also I know there are many topics related to reading a text file, I have read them but I still have this problem..

Comment: put a bit more code. How is tempWord,maxWords defined?

Comment: What is that `lineCounter` function actually doing?  To read a file from beginning to end, you should check the return value of `fgets` and `feof(finput)`.  Also note that using `getline` instead of `fgets` can greatly help simplifying and robustifying your code.

Comment: `maxWords` is too small is a candidate issue.

Comment: Nice to see `maxWords`, but then what is the maximum number of `char` in a line?  If it is 199 or more, code needs a larger buffer.

Comment: I edited the code to be more detailed. Linecounter works fine i debugged it and tested it returns the correct integer result all it does is count the amount of newlines in the text file

Comment: Let's get this straight...  You iterate the file, looking for newlines, and count them. Then you iterate it again looking for lines?

Comment: I just tested the maxWords possible problem. It is not the problem if i replace the variable maxWords with lets say 1000, or 600 the same problem persists

Comment: Please ignore lineCounter because even if i replace it with lets say int 1500 it still has the same problem

Comment: The comment of @5gon12eder should be an answer, it's correct. With a small correction, you should check either the return value of `fgets()` **or** the output value of `feof()` **and** `ferror()`.

Comment: If it is a possible buffer issue does that means i have to change printf to something like this?: printf("%100s", tempWord)

Comment: Does code print the first 150 of 1500 lines?

Comment: @Fernando if i check the return value being NULL how will that help because if the method returns NULL that means it doesn't read it? Do i handle the error with an if-statement or something?

Comment: @chux the output prints the text correct but usually around aprox 150 - 200 lines in the text

Comment: Suggest `while (fgets(tempWord, maxWords, finput) != NULL) printf("%s", tempWord);`

Comment: @geforce:that method will return NULL if it reaches end of file, check the sample here: http://www.codingunit.com/c-tutorial-file-io-using-text-files

Comment: Possible need a `fflush(stdout)` after the loop.  Without seeing more code, further ideas are approaching guesses.

Comment: Suggest `printf("%d:%s", i, tempWord);`

Comment: @chux thanks for suggesting that i find a new problem... soo when i changed the while condition to your suggestion it prints the exact same but now when it ends at 150-200 text lines after it prints "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Comment: should i perhaps use memset or something to remove allocation or memory or something?

Comment: 1) Are you checking the `fgets()` return value?  Sounds like you are.  If it returns `NULL`, do _not_ print the buffer - that is UB.  2) Out of space with `char tempWord[maxWords];`?  Too deep a stack?

Comment: No need for `memset()` nor "something to remove allocation" base on posted code.   I think the problem is in other unposted code.

Comment: Yes i am checking fgets value in while condition like you stated if it isnt NULL it prints the word otherwise the loop stops. Thanks for the possible issues i have no more time to check it now but when i get back from work i will review your suggestions again thanks @chux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This small program should print out the line number and the line itself of an entire text file.

```
#define INPUT_FILE 1
#define LINE_LEN 200

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int line_num;
    char string[LINE_LEN];
    FILE *file;
    if((file = fopen(argv[INPUT_FILE], "r")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open input file\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    line_num = 1;
    while( fgets(string, LINE_LEN, file) != NULL ) {
        line_num++
        printf( "Line %d: <%s>\n", line_num, string);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:
Initialized `line_num` to 1 and added the tags as suggested by @chux

Comment: For further debug information, suggest `"Line %d: <%s>\n"`, something printable around the line.